# A technique for weakening a universally quantified statement

Tags: logic, reference-request, terminology, propositional-calculus

In a recent question I was investigating (I will not disclose the question here, but will provide some analogous examples) I was trying to apply a certain restricted concept to a broader context. This property had the form

\begin{align}
\forall_{x,\in X}[\alpha(x)]
\end{align}

But the variable $x$ appears twice in the formula for $\alpha$, and thus we can make a new statement $\alpha'$ which depends on two variables and satisfies:

\begin{align}
\forall_{x}[\alpha'(x,x) \iff \alpha(x)]
\end{align}

So it is essentially the same statement as $\alpha$ but viewing the two appearances of $x$ in $\alpha$ as separate. This then allows us to create a new and weaker condition of a set, namely

\begin{align}
\forall_{x\in X}\exists_{y\in X}[\alpha'(x,y)]
\end{align}

Which is clearly weaker than the first condition, since if $\alpha(x)$ is true for some specific $x$ then $\alpha'(x,x)$ is true. The process can also sometimes be done in reverse to obtain a significant strengthening of a statement, for example in the definition of continuity of a function on $\mathbb{R}$, we have something of the form

\begin{align}
\forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}[\alpha(\varepsilon,\delta)]
\end{align}

If instead we quantified

\begin{align}
\forall_{\varepsilon}[\alpha(\varepsilon,\varepsilon)]
\end{align}

Then the class of functions satisfying this will still be continuous, but they now have some other restrictions (Probably something resembling a restriction on their derivative, but a bit more nuanced)

*Note that this strengthening was also accompanied by a weakening of the domain from which $\varepsilon$ is taken, we don't need to worry about $\delta$ being negative when $\varepsilon$ is positive anymore.

My question is, is this a technique that has shown up enough in the past that it has a name? And what are some other interesting instances that can be seen as a version of this?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this before, no. Reducing the number of quantifiers in a formula is of concern to descriptive set theory, so there could be something there.

Comment: I've seen similar techniques when it comes to assessing the complexity of formula. Related concepts would be the Levy Heirarchy, and the absoluteness of formula which can be written as both existential statements, and universal statements.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I wasn't able to derive $\forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}[\alpha(\varepsilon,\delta)]\to \forall_{\varepsilon>0}[\alpha(\varepsilon,\varepsilon)]$

Comment: @DanChristensen this won't be true in general, it is a much stronger condition, it is just an example of how a statement can be strengthened by eliminating one of the quantifiers. If you go in the opposite direction, weakening the statement, the derivation should be obvious. If this wasn't clear, feel free to suggest ways that I can improve the phrasing of the question

Comment: @DanChristensen I have switched two paragraphs, it should be more clear now